# Do this algorithm terminates?

Tags: analysis, algorithms, proof-writing, computational-complexity

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ denote a $p$ dimensional data point (a vector). I have two sets $A = \{x_1, .., x_n\}$ and $B = \{x_{n+1}, .., x_{n+m}\}$. So $|A| = n$, and $|B| = m$. Given $k \in \mathbb{N^*}$, let $d_x^{(A, k)}$ denote the mean Euclidean distance from $x$ to its $k$ nearest points in $A$; and $d_x^{(B, k)}$ denote the mean Euclidean distance from $x$ to its $k$ nearest points in $B$.

I have the following algorithm:

- $A' = \{ x_i \in A \mid d_{x_i}^{A, k)} > d_{x_i}^{(B, k)} \}$ ... (1)
- $B' = \{ x_i \in B \mid d_{x_i}^{A, k)} < d_{x_i}^{(B, k)}$ ... (2)
- A = $\{ x_i \in A \mid x_i \not\in A' \} \cup B'$ ... (3)
- B = $\{ x_i \in B \mid x_i \not\in B' \} \cup A'$ ... (4)
- Repeat (1), (2), (3) and (4) until: (no element moves from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$, that is A' and B' become empty) or (|A| $\leq$ or |B| $\leq$ 1)

Do this algorithm terminates, and if it so, is it possible to easily prove it ?

**Note:** the $k$ nearest points to $x$ in a set $S$, means: the $k$ points (others than $x$) in $S$, having the smallest Euclidean distance to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $p=1$ and $k=1$. Consider $A=\{0,3\}$ and $B=\{2,5\}$.

- $d_0^A=3$ and $d_0^B=2$
- $d_2^A=1$ and $d_2^B=3$
- $d_3^A=3$ and $d_3^B=1$
- $d_5^A=2$ and $d_5^B=3$

  So $A'=A$ and $B'=B$, so $A$ becomes $B$ and $B$ becomes $A$, and the algorithm never stops.

Comment: Thank you for your example. If as soon as I find an element x in A having $d_x^A > d_x^B$ I put it in B, and as soon as I find an element x in B having $d_x^A < d_x^B$ I put it in B, would it be the same (algorithm never stops) ?

Comment: Yes, I think that the algorithm would eventually stop, but in that case there are examples where everything end with $A$ empty or $B$ empty, only depending of the order you choose to "find" your elements. So you could probably put everything in $A$ in one step, it would be much quicker :)